# What is the purpose of double `w` in `ps -ww`?

Tags: ps

From https://askubuntu.com/a/831521/1471

```
ps -Flww -p THE_PID
```

I was wondering what the purpose for double `w` is? Is it the same as just one `w`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`man ps`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) is saying:

```
w      Wide output.  Use this option twice for unlimited width.
-w     Wide output.  Use this option twice for unlimited width.
```

either in this way `ww` or `-w -w` or any combination of these two.

Answer (score 7):

one w is "wide", two w's is "weally wide"

Answer (score 2):

With single 'w' output of 'ps' is truncated at terminal's window boundary. With two 'w' ('-ww') long lines may use several terminal rows to be completely visible. Reduce width of your terminal and you will easily notice the difference.